# Ruby: convert "US/Eastern" time zone names to "Central Time (US & Canada)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I've got an old database with time zone formats like:

```
US/Eastern
Australia/Melbourne
```

In my new Rails app, I'm saving them as:

```
Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Melbourne
```

How can I convert the old to the new?  I've been messing around with ActiveSupport::TimeZone, but can't figure out the right combination to get from one to the other.

I was hoping I could create a new object, then return the newly formatted name, but it just returns the name I gave it.  Example:

```
> tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("US/Eastern")
=> (GMT-05:00) US/Eastern
> tz.name
=> "US/Eastern"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty ugly, but it's the only way I've found to do it:

```
city = TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Eastern').instance_eval('@linked_timezone').name
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.invert[city]
```

**Edit:**

For this code to work with either city or zone, you can do this:

```
zone = TZInfo::Timezone.get(zone_name)
city = (zone.instance_eval('@linked_timezone') || zone).name
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.invert[city]
```

Comment: For the Melbourne example, don't hit the @linked_timezone variable, since there isn't one (you've already got a city).

(I've updated the code above.)

Comment: "TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Eastern').instance_eval('@linked_timezone').name"
is giving me error.